# penaho how to compare two tables and get the row that is not same in pentaho

Tags: merge, pentaho, pdi, spoon

I have two tables in pentaho. Can I use Merge Rows to get the row which is different in target table . I do not want to merge data to target table. How can i do that. please help.

Comment: If the tables' rows are merged correctly, then you can compare each row using filter rows.

Comment: as far as I understand you only want to read the data which are not present in the target table, you can write a simple select query and handle it inside table input step.